# How to display images in modal bootstrap using AngularJS and ng-repeat derective?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, image-gallery

i have simple AngularJS application, i'm trying display images in **modal** use **bootstrap**, all photos at page i'm displaying use **ng-repeat** directive:

```
<div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="photo_item in allPhotosOfSingleAlbum">
   <img id="myImg" ng-src="../Files/Photos/{{photo_item.link}}" width="250px" height="160px" class="img-rounded" />
</div>
```

and i have the code of modal:

```
<div id="imageModal" class="modal">
     <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('imageModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
     <img class="modal-content" id="img01" />
</div>
```

Tell me please, how i can use it both ng-repeat and modal ? 
Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move your first code where you have ng-repeat in modal and you should be able to show your images there.

```
<div id="imageModal" class="modal">
     <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('imageModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
     <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="photo_item in allPhotosOfSingleAlbum">
            <img id="myImg" ng-src="../Files/Photos/{{photo_item.link}}" width="250px" height="160px" class="img-rounded" />
        </div>
</div>
```